# What would happen if we create a number that multiplied by zero is equal to 1?

Tags: complex-numbers

I had an idea, if we created the imaginary number line so we have a solution for x^2=-1, what would happen if we create a number line for 1/0=j. Would it be beneficial in any way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You're reinventing the orders of infinity

Comment: You'll lose many basic algebraic properties, for example, the distributive law gives $1 = j*0 = j(0+0) = j*0+j*0 =2$  ...

Comment: My thinking was that progress has been made by breaking some of the rules, as it was rhe case of I, I wonder what is the point where we have to break other rules. I it's used in physics maybe we need a new set of numbers for quantum physics

Comment: The imaginary number $i$ doesn’t break any algebraic rules.  But there are number systems which approximate, in some sense, division by 0 (nonstandard reals, for example) but they aren’t as simple as “declare a new symbol to solve a particular equation and see what happens”, the way $i$ is.